# Find $\cos(\frac{\pi}{p})\cos(\frac{\pi}{p^{2}})\cos(\frac{\pi}{p^{3}})...$ where $p$ is an odd prime number.

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-product

Yesterday, I encountered the product $\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+2}})$ in a post which is unfortunately deleted by its poster after some negative comments.

I found the product in the following way:
Let $A_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+2}})$ and $B_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+2}})$. Then $A_nB_n=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}B_{n-1}$ and we have
$A_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+2}})}$. Thus, $\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+2}})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n=\frac{2}{\pi}.$

Then I thought about the infinite product
$$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{\pi}{p^{k+1}})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{p})\cos(\frac{\pi}{p^{2}})\cos(\frac{\pi}{p^{3}})...$$
where $p$ is an odd prime number. I am stuck.

Any comments or answers are wellcome.

Comment: I don't suspect there is a closed formula, but it definitely converges.

Comment: Is there any reason to restrict the question to primes, rather than integers $>2?$

Comment: No. I couldn't solve for $p=3$. That is why.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to restrict to $p$ odd, since the product of zero if $p$ is even. But I doubt having $p$ prime adds much.

Comment: The fundamental reason $p=2$ is nice is that $$\prod_{i=0}^{n}(1+w^{2^i})=\frac{w^{2^{n+1}}-1}{w-1}$$ This lets you write $\prod_{i=0}^n \cos(2^ix)$ in a nice closed formula, with $w=e^{2ix}.$ But when $p>2,$ there is no equivalent closed formula. The closest you can get is: $$\prod_0^n \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} w^{jp^i} = \frac{w^{p^{n+1}}-1}{w-1}.$$ But that won't given a product of cosines, but a product of sums of cosines.

Comment: An alternate variation is to let $f_p(x)=\frac1pU_{p-1}(x)$ and $U_{n}$ are the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. Then $f_2(x)=x, f_3(x)=\frac13(4x^2-1).$ And we again get: $$\prod_{i=0}^{n} f(\cos(p^i\theta))=\frac{\sin p^{n+1}\theta}{p^{n+1}\sin\theta}$$ and you get: $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} f(\cos(x/p^i))=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Your case is $p=2, x=\pi/2.$ This formula works for all integers $p>1,$ but is obviously not what you wanted.

Comment: For the case $p=3,$ you get $f_p(\cos x)=\frac{1}{3}(4\cos^2 x-1)=\frac13(2\cos 2x+1).$ So you get $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac13(2\cos(\pi/3^i)+1)=\frac{1}{\pi}.$$

Comment: The last product is $\frac{2}{\pi}$ again... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=product_%28k%3D1%29%5E20+%281%2F3%29%282cos%28pi%2F3%5Ek%29%2B1%29

Comment: Yep, had a brain blip computing $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $x=\pi/2.$ @BobDobbs

Comment: In general, for $p$ odd, $$f_p(\cos x)=\frac1p\left(1+2\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2} \cos(2jx)\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing
$$P_n=\prod_{k=0}^\infty \cos\left(\frac \pi {p^{k+1} } \right)\quad \implies \quad \log(P_n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\log\left( \cos\left(\frac \pi {p^{k+1} }\right) \right)$$ is not the most pleasant to compute.

We can use
$$\log\left( \cos\left(\frac \pi {x }\right) \right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{2^{2 n-3} \pi ^{2 n} (E_{2 n-1}(1)-E_{2 n-1}(0))}{n \,(2 n-1)!\, x^{2n}}$$ whcih gives

$$\log(P_n)=-\frac {\pi^2}{2(p^2-1)}-\frac {\pi^4}{12(p^4-1)}-\frac {\pi^6}{45(p^6-1)}-\frac{17 \pi ^8}{2520 \left(p^8-1\right)}-\frac{31 \pi ^{10}}{14175 \left(p^{10}-1\right)}-\cdots$$

Computing for a few integer values of $p$ (only the terms given above were used)

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \text{estimate} & \text{solution}  \\
 3  &\color{red}{ -0.76}0890548037401  &
      -0.762980593156087 \\
 4  &\color{red}{-0.3672}09038523256  &
      -0.367260902722768 \\
 5  &\color{red}{ -0.2201}77685381150  & 
      -0.220180927677961 \\
 6  &\color{red}{ -0.147762}045679447  &
      -0.147762392383186 \\
 7  &\color{red}{ -0.106384}062181141  &
      -0.106384115219117 \\
 8  & \color{red}{-0.0803979}74954449  & 
      -0.080397985451577 \\
 9  & \color{red}{-0.06296418}6060146  & 
      -0.062964188584209 \\
 10 &\color{red}{ -0.050680335}287169  & 
      -0.050680335994092 \\
 11 &\color{red}{ -0.041690186}591224  & 
      -0.041690186815090 \\
 12 & \color{red}{-0.034907897}472455  &
      -0.034907897550889 \\
 13 & \color{red}{-0.029662552}271415  &
      -0.029662552301324 \\
 14 & \color{red}{-0.0255208681}33972  &
      -0.025520868146228 \\
 15 & \color{red}{-0.02219261524}3287  &
      -0.022192615248630 \\
 16 & \color{red}{-0.01947731794}2376  & 
      -0.019477317944835 \\
 17 & \color{red}{-0.01723281562}4760  & 
      -0.017232815625946 \\
 18 & \color{red}{-0.015355986601}374  &
      -0.015355986601970 \\
 19 &\color{red}{-0.01377053020}6716  & 
      -0.013770530207027 \\
 20 & \color{red}{-0.012418995869}403  &
      -0.012418995869571
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! I had shared a post about Euler number. Also, in terms of Bernoulli numbers, $\ln\cos(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(4^n-1)\zeta(2n)}{n\pi^{2n}}x^{2n}$.